# Asp.net on linux VPS hosting

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, vps

I Have a VPS hosting on which I've installed Ubuntu 13.04.
I'm willing to host an ASP.NET app on it.
Is it possible to install a virual machine and set up a Windows envirement for hosting C# app ?
I'm trying to avoid mono plateform.

Comment: There is no way to avoid Mono, or you implement your own CLR or utilize a less popular open source CLR implementation (dotGNU or others) which is incomplete nor stable.

Comment: Isn't possible to install Vmware and Windows server inside of it ?

Comment: If the VPS does give you a physical box, you might install VMware. But usually they give you a virtual one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all VPS providers won't let you add another level of visualization, I ended by picking up a VPS that runs on Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

Better go for VPS with Windows platform. If you want to host asp.net application then opting for VPS with Windows platform is the ideal choice.

Comment: Yeah that's the most suitable choice.